Update CMAKE variable from command line call, each time a specific make target is called?
If I have the set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "2024-02-15") in my CMakeLists.txt that does INCLUDE(CPack), then after I create the Makefile with cmake ../, I can call make package, and the resulting .deb file will have the specified version string in its filename.
I can also do execute_process( COMMAND date +'%Y-%m-%d' OUTPUT_VARIABLE CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR) and have the output of the date +'%Y-%m-%d' written into the CMake CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR variable; however the command is only called once, at configure time, when cmake ../ is called - and the resulting output is hardcoded in CPackConfig.cmake and CPackSourceConfig.cmake.
What can I do, to have a Cmake variable - or even, a Makefile variable - be updated from the results of calling some external program, every time make with some specific target (like make package) is called?

OK, found the answer in a comment here: set cmake variable from custom command before every build

"I want to run a command and pass its output to a compile definition each time make runs" - This is impossible, CMake generates Makefile with hardcoded compiler options. You may, however, wrap a compiler with custom script or program, which adds needed options.

for alternatives: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html says:

execute_process runs commands while CMake is configuring the project, prior to build system generation. Use the add_custom_target() and add_custom_command() commands to create custom commands that run at build time.

Note add_custom_target(targetname ALL ...) runs everytime at end of build, and so will run first in make upload as well - the question is how to propagate the variable value ...
